# Need to split a line of text in an editable cell deliminated by + signs

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need a VBA code to split a line of text in an editable cell deliminated by + signs and then to put the split text in a column separately while keeping the original cell unchanged. Also I need this to update automatically as I change the cell. I have looked through many posts and I cannot find one that answers this question.

Below is the code that I have tried so far:

```
 Sub NameTest()

     Dim txt As String
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim FullName As Variant

     txt = ActiveCell.Value

     FullName = Split(txt, " ")

     For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)

         Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)

     Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub NameTest1()

   Dim v As Variant

   v = Split(ActiveCell.Value2, "+")

   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(v) + 1) = v

End Sub
```

---

Comment: The second one is not working while the first one does (Excel 2013)